# How to change the mongod db query to aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-shell

1. I have three queries and now I want to change this to MongoDB aggregation
   and below is the code:

   ```
         db.mycollection.count({$and:[$requestB:{$exists:false},[$requestC:{$exists:false}]})
         db.mycollection.count({requestB:{$exists:true}})
         db.mycollection.count({requestC:{$exists:true}})
   ```
2. Now i want to change this code to aggregation but it did not work

   ```
      db.mycollection.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        '_id' : { user_id: '$user_id'},
        requestA_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {$and: [{$eq: ["$requestB", null]}, {$eq: ["requestC", null]}}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        requestB_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {requestB:{'$exists':true}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        requestC_count: { $sum: {
            $cond: [ {requestC:{'$exists':true}}, 1, 0 ]
        } },
    } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user_id: '$_id.user_id',
        requestA_count: 1,
        requestB_count: 1,
        requestC_count: 1
    } }
    ] );
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$type` instead of `$exists` inside `$group`,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": { user_id: "$user_id" },
      requestA_count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                { $ne: [{$type: "$requestA"}, "missing"] }, 
                { $eq: [{$type: "$requestB"}, "missing"] }, 
                { $eq: [{$type: "$requestC"}, "missing"] }
              ]
            },  // you need to close bracket here not below
            1, 0
          ]
        }
      },
      requestB_count: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $ne: [{ $type: "$requestB" }, "missing"] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      requestC_count: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $ne: [ { $type: "$requestC" }, "missing" ] }, 1, 0] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_id: "$_id.user_id",
      requestA_count: 1,
      requestB_count: 1,
      requestC_count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4grX2oLuuaK)

Comment: thanks, form your link, why requestA_count total number is 0?  {
    "requestA": 1,
    "user_id": 1
  },
This object does not contain requestB and requestC so  requestA_count should be 1 not 0

Comment: requestA_count  counts all the document which do not have the field requestB and  requestC

Comment: My idea is to find the total number of requestB filed exist in the document, requestC exist in the document. requestA is to find and count the object do not contain requestB and requestC

Comment: ok check now its corrected, my intention is to give a way how you can do, that the logical changes you can change it right?